# How to properly connect to Project Online via REST API

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, ms-project

I've been trying to connect to my Project Online instance using the REST API, and as a first step to simply list the projects and validate the connection works. I've reviewed various documentation, which has been a mess of conflicting suggestions. I'm hoping to get some guidance on how to correctly do so. The list projects action seems to be listed as:
http://<pwa_site>/_api/ProjectData/Projects

Our Project Online URL is: https://project.microsoft.com/.com/en-US
However, since the examples are using , I presumed we needed to set up a PWA site. Luckily, it seems I previously did that as part of attemps earlier in the year to get REST working. It's available under the "My PWA site" in my settings in Project Online, and is currently:
https://2023.sharepoint.com/sites/pwa

So, I created a sample GET request as follows:
https://2023.sharepoint.com/sites/pwa/_api/ProjectData/Projects

That just gives me a "Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation" response. I even tried without the sites/pwa just in case, but that didn't work either: https://2023.sharepoint.com/_api/ProjectData/Projects

Although the code examples didn't mention it, it seemed weird that there wouldn't be any authentication headers included with the HTTP requests, so I tried putting in a basic Auth header like we do for Jira, but that didn't work either.

So I was hoping for some insight. The only other thing I can think of is that the "2023" URL I'm currently using is not the URL I should be for accessing the REST API, and that some kind of token Id needs to be generated for use in the URL. But none of the documentation I've read is very clear on that.

Comment: The PA url is actually company2023, where company is our company name. Seems stackoverflow didn't like the greater/less than I put around it and filtered it out as a html tag